# What does "@" symbol mean in "import { Component } from '@angular/core';" statement?

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm reading Angular 2 ["5 Min Quickstart"](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and there is such a line:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';"
```

I can't figure out, what does `@` symbol make in that import? TypeScript docs also don't say anything about that.

What does it mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding npm package @-prefix: @angular/router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/understanding-npm-package-prefix-angular-router)

Answer (score 116):

Also of relevance is that you can use the `@` symbol scoping for non-npm packages as well. You can use this in your project as a short way of referring to different directories.

i.e.

```
import { MyService } from '@services/my.service';
import { HelloWorldComponent } from '@components/hello-world.component';
```

instead of

```
import { MyService } from '../../../../my.service';
import { HelloWorldComponent } from '../shared/deeply/nested/hello-world/hello-world.component';
```

To do this, you simply configure your tsconfig.json file (at root of project) like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {

    // omitted...

    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@services/*": ["app/path/to/services/*"],
      "@components/*": ["app/somewhere/deeply/nested/*"],
      "@environments/*": ["environments/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

See the full details at [Angular Firebase](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/shorten-typescript-imports-in-an-angular-project/)

Comment: Just for others to know, if you get "Can't find module" in VS Code, CMD + SHIFT + P then type reload window, you should stop having the error. (Suppose for win/linux: CTRL + SHIFT + P)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it's given some idea about @ symbol in angular

Comment: Alternately/further to @JosephBriggs suggestion for VS Code "Cannot find module", try "TypeScript: Reload Project" from the Command Palette.

Comment: If you're using ts-node, you may have issues with this... to resolve the issue, install  `tsconfig-paths` npm package

Answer (score 35):

@scope_name/package_name

This is NPM feature, scoped name, anything between @ and slash / will be your scope name.

[npm scope document](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope)

Answer (score 10):

this is just a naming convention that Angular uses. Since the release they renamed it to @angular/core in stead of angular2/core.

It references the core components of the framework.

(found in post - [angularjs 2 with angular-material @angular/core not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182093/angularjs-2-with-angular-material-angular-core-not-found))

Comment: I think it's a bit more than that ... in the question you reference it explains that @ prefix allows related npm packages to be grouped more neatly under a folder with an @ prefix rather than polluting the node_module folder root. For more info, see https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/scoped-packages