# Why do some npm packages start with @?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Is there anything different about the dependencies that start with `@`?

Does that mean or imply something?
I don't see any info about that. Take a look at my `node_modules` folder:
[image: folder view]

**Fortawesome** starts with `@` and does not contain the typical `fortawesome.css` file.
So is it the same? Or does the `@` indicate something?

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "ng-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.4",
    "animate.css": "^3.6.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jasny-bootstrap": "^3.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

This question is not about **Angular**.

Comment: This question fits under ["software tools commonly used by programmers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) so I'd argue it's blatantly *on*-topic.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to say, @Kos.

Comment: This is on topic BTW. @ specifies grouping and scoping similar packages together. The packages preceded with @ are scoped packages.

Comment: Can you post your `package.json`?

Comment: read this official blog for naming rule http://blog.npmjs.org/post/168978377570/new-package-moniker-rules/

Comment: @Oscar While the other question is in the context of angular, **the same answer applies**. You'll notice that the answer does not mention angular. It is not specific to angular. Should we also ask it with a `@react` prefixed package? What about vuejs, should we ask yet another question that asks the same but about vuejs packages? (Note that a duplicate is still "on-topic", just already asked).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> If a package's name begins with **@**, then it is a scoped package. The scope is everything in between the **@** and the **slash**

```
@scope/project-name
```

### How to Initialize a Scoped Package

To create a scoped package, you simply use a package name that starts with your scope.

```
{
  "name": "@username/project-name"
}
```

More details, Please visit [scoped package](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/scoped-packages)

and

[What does "@" symbol mean in "import { Component } from '@angular/core';" statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372816/what-does-symbol-mean-in-import-component-from-angular-core-statem)

Comment: I dont think `@scope/project-name` is a good example as the scoping may be the project name and the later a package within that project. For example `@babel/core` ... Babel is the project and core is the package.

Comment: When used in package names, scopes are preceded by an @ symbol and followed by a slash, e.g.

@somescope/somepackagename

Scopes are a way of grouping related packages together, and also affect a few things about the way npm treats the package.  As well as can signal authority / ownership.

Reference Link: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scope

Answer (score 26):

**@** refer to  npm [scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope):

> When used in package names, scopes are preceded by an @ symbol and followed by a slash

Scopes are a way of grouping related packages together.

For instance, your *package.json* contains some `@angular/` prefixed dependencies (@angular/animations, @angular/compiler-cli, etc) which means that they are under `angular` scope. The code of all those dependencies is under `@angular` directory.

Comment: There aren't any `/`s or equivalent in the names in the screenshot, so I'm guessing the `@angular` is not actually a package, but a scope, and there will be sub-folders for the individual packages?

Comment: @IMSoP Each package is stored in `node_modules/<pkg-name>. So `@angular/cli` would be inside the `@angular/cli` folder. Since the OP did not open the `@angular` folder, you can't see the `cli` folder inside.

Answer (score 14):

packages with **@** denotes the organisation. In this case the organisation is Fortawesome. It contains multiple packages (you can see it inside @fortawesome folder).

As described on [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/docs/orgs/)

> Creating an Organization on npm gives you an Organization scope under which you can have your own namespace for packages.

Scopes are great for many reasons, for example:

- Maintain a fork of a package, e.g. @the-best/request.
- Avoiding name
  disputes with popular names, e.g. @the-best/cat.
- Improving internal discovery of Organization-supported packages (they're all in a single namespace!)

Hope that helps.