# What does it mean by import * from '@/components/my_module.vue'?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I saw someone's code today and there is a line like this:

`import my_module from '@/components/share/my_module.vue';`

Can you please tell me what is this `@` mean?

I tried searching on Google but don't know the terms to search.

Thank you.

Comment: It's likely a custom alias as defined in a `tsconfig.json`,`jsconfig.json`, or whatever build system config file they may be using.

Comment: `scoped packages` find more at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372816/what-does-symbol-mean-in-import-component-from-angular-core-statem

Comment: the @ symbol is probably a path option in the build system - in vuejs2 it usually refers to the `src` folder in the project