# When to have @types

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-composition-api

As I am reading some tutorials just like this one [here](https://logaretm.com/blog/type-safe-provide-inject/)
I noticed the author has introduced `@type`

as I am new into vue, I do not know what `@type` is! and iI do not have it in my `.vue` project.

would you please tell me in what scenario or case I would need to have `@type` and what it should container

Comment: The question is worded incorrecty as `@/types` != `@types`. The latter refers to scoped npm packages that augment the libs that don't have their own types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@/types` refers to a folder called  `types` the `@` means the folder is non-npm packages (see more at the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372816/what-does-symbol-mean-in-import-component-from-angular-core-statem) for more information)
Usually you create this folder in order to store your interface/types related to your application. (see more at the following [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) for more information)
In the tutorial you can see that is importing a type called Product from this folder.
I hope I was able to help you.
good luck for the future !

Edit :
Historically, Vue used javascript as the programming language in its framework. In addition to this, Microsoft has developed Typescript which, as its name suggests, is a language similar to Javascript but with types. You can read the documentation on this subject in the link in my second reply.
As mentioned in the tutorial in your post, Typescript is now supported in version 3 of Vue. In the tutorial of your post, the author makes the choice to use Typescript and thus Types/Interface that Typescript propose as I was able to explain it in my answer.
I hope this is clearer for you.
I can only advise you to read the Typescript documentation and to use this language in the development of your future Vue applications.
In addition, the vue documentation is very well provided with examples using Typescript.

Comment: execuse me please, is vue a type-script?

Comment: I edited my post in order to explain more in details what Typescript is, because my text was too long I edited my post. I hope it can help you.

Comment: `@/types` != `@types`